# nexusUI widgets inside a jQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am using [nexusUI](http://nexusosc.com/) for a project and would like to use templates but discovered that  don't seem to be rendered. I suppose it is because of the missing canvas context but I am not quite sure how to go about it... Any pointers?

Here's the code that illustrates the issue:

```
<!-- This renders fine, as expected -->
<div> <canvas nx='button'></canvas> </div>

<!-- this is my rendering container -->
<div class="nxContainer"></div>
<!-- and a template that should contain a "dial" widget -->
<script type="text/html" id="test">
    <div data-content="widget"> </div>
</script>

<!-- counter example to make sure that loadTemplate is actually working -->
<div class="Container"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="test2">
    <div data-content="text"> </div>
</script>

$(function () {

    var nxus = {
        widget: "<canvas nx='dial'></canvas>",
        text: "Boo!"
    }
    $(".nxContainer").loadTemplate("#test", nxus);
    $(".Container").loadTemplate("#test2", nxus);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/745vhffb/4/

**edit:**
So after poking around some more and looking through the source code of the nexusUI library, it looks like I found a solution and I updated my fiddle, which is now at revision #9 (I exceeded my quota for posting links).

```
nx.elemTypeArr.push("myslide");
var mySlider = "myslide";
var x = new slider('myslide');
x.init();
```

So basically, it looks like I have to take care of registering the new widget with nx and instantiating it.

Comment: Hi djiamnot, sorry I missed this when you first asked it. 

Yes, the version of nexusUI you were using only found canvases that are on the page when window.onload fires. 

The latest version of nexusUI, though, has a method `nx.add("dial")` which lets you dynamically add widgets to your page at any time. This version **nexusUI 1.0** was released in December at [nexusosc.com](http://nexusosc.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a complete solution to my issue:

```
function instantiateWidget(container, template, widgetType, id, destination){
    var sub = {
        widget: "<canvas nx='" + widgetType + "' id='" + id + "'></canvas>"
    }
    $(container).loadTemplate(template, sub);
    nx.elemTypeArr.push(id);
    eval(id + " = new " + widgetType + "('" + id + "', " + destination + ");");
    eval(id + ".init();");
}
```

and then

```
instantiateWidget("#nxContainer", "#test", "dial", "local");
```

and this will populate the container with the template:

```
<div id="nxContainer"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="test">
    <div data-content-append="widget"> </div>
</script>
```

The nx widgets need to be instantiated in order to obtain their canvas context and only then they become available. There is probably a more elegant way of doing this but for now it will do for me.